# Winui3, Listview, inside flyout, bound to obsevablecollection, not updating

Tags: c#, listview, observablecollection, winui-3, flyout

I am currently displaying a `ListView` in a `Flyout` of a `DropDownButton`. I have an `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ListView`. During the app initialization, a method that clears the contents of the `ObservableCollection` and adds some elements to it, is called, this should update the `ListView` and show some elements on the UI, but an empty container is shown instead.

XAML:

```
<DropDownButton Content="Super long name that does not fit on the dropdown">
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom" >
         
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>

            <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind _presenter.ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList, Mode=OneWay}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="ListName" 
                SelectedValuePath="SelectedName"
                CornerRadius="10"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="OnMasterChannelDropdownSelectionChange"
            />

        </Flyout>
    </DropDownButton.Flyout>
</DropDownButton>
```

Main Window (List Initialization call):

```
public MainWindow()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();

   _presenter = new Presenter(Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread());
   _controller = new Controller();
   // Initialize states
   _controller.GetDubwareDeviceInfo(); // Trigger a flow that ends up calling the  UpdateOutputDevices on the Presenter
}
```

Presenter code:

```
public class Presenter
{
   public Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue DispatcherQueue { get; }
   public ViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();

   public void UpdateOutputDevices(List<OutputDeviceDs> outputDeviceDsList)
   {
       DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
       {
           ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList.Clear();
           ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList.Add(new("", "SelectDevice", "None"));

           foreach (OutputDeviceDs outputDeviceDs in outputDeviceDsList)
           {
               ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList.Add(new(outputDeviceDs.Name, outputDeviceDs.Name, outputDeviceDs.Name));
           }

           Debug.WriteLine($" Updated output device list, outputDeviceDsList has {outputDeviceDsList.Count} elements and OutputDeviceViewModelList has {ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList.Count} elements");
       });
   }
}
```

View model (contains the ObservableCollection):

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() { }
    public ObservableCollection<OutputDeviceViewModel> OutputDeviceViewModelList { get; set; } = new();    
}
```

Model:

```
public class OutputDeviceViewModel
{
   public string Id { get; set;}
   public string SelectedName { get; set;}
   public string ListName { get; set;}

   public OutputDeviceViewModel(string id, string selectedName, string listName)
   {
       Id = id; 
       SelectedName = selectedName;    
       ListName = listName;
   }
}
```

When the app is executed Debug print show that the list is populated with 3 elements

[image: List update print]

But an empty container is shown when the dropdown is open

[image: Empty dropdown list]

Is only after interacting with other elements of the page that the list shows three elements.

Currently I have managed force the update of the `ListView` by creating a non visible `ListView`, that is bound to the same `ObservableCollection`, at the same level of the `DropDownButton`

as such:

```
<ListView 
   Visibility="Collapsed"            
   ItemsSource="{x:Bind _presenter.ViewModel.OutputDeviceViewModelList, Mode=OneWay}" 
/>
<DropDownButton Content="Super long name that does not fit on the dropdown">
    <DropDownButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom" >
         ...
    ...
...
```

With this workaround the list shows the 3 elements as soon as the `ObservableCollection` is updated during initialization

[image: Dropdown with 3 elements]

Does anyone has any clue why this this workaround fixes the `ListView` elements not updating as soon as the list is udpated?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  Please file an issue in WinUI's Git.

Comment: Thought the same. I posted it here just in case I was overlooking something. I will post it on their github.